# Pandas read_csv modified original data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file:

> 7/20/2017,ABC,U,2017,,,,37.7,F
>
> 7/20/2017,ABC,V,2017,,,,39.295,F

After using

> pd.read_csv(path,header = None)

the numerical number was changed to:

```
data[7][1]
Out[3]: 37.700000000000003

data[7][2]
Out[4]: 39.295000000000002
```

Does anyone has any thoughts what's the cause and remedy for this issue?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue due to [floating point number representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

If you really need the numbers to be exact, you would need to use a decimal data type:

```
from decimal import Decimal
df['column'] = df['column'].astype(Decimal)
```